# How to call a Segue from left to right?

Tags: xcode, storyboard, segue

Ive programatically set up the segue to navigate to my 2nd view controller - but it only changes scenes from bottom to top. I need the app to navigate from left to right... This is my code:

```
-(IBAction)nextView;

{

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"next" sender:self];
}
```

So when you press the button "Start" it changes to the 2nd view, from bottom to top - ***not right to left <---- which I need for my app!

Comment: Be clear with your question and clarification....In question you are mentioning left to right and in clarification you have mentioned right to left.

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 kinds of segues, Push, Model, Custom.

- Model, pop from the bottom.
- Push, comes in from the right.

Go to your storyboard and change your segue to push. Also note, your 1st viewController must be embedded in navigation controller, otherwise you'll get a warning.